# Send two different emails after form submission

Tags: php, forms, email

When a user submits a form, I want one email to come to me with the form fields and a separate email to be sent to the user confirming their submission (two separate emails with different content).

I tried the following form, but only the first email is generated. The second email is never received.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.example.com";

$to = 'info@example.com';
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers .= "From: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message .= "Content of Message 1";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$message = ""; 

$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'Subject';
$headers .= "From: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message .= "Content of Message 2";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$message = "";

echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="1; URL='.$url.'">';

?>
```

What would prevent the second message from sending?

Comment: are you sure you caught $_POST['email'] well? Also, you keep appending the $headers. You should probably set $headers = "" just as for $message

Comment: Try echoing the value of $_POST['email'] to verify that it is being passed properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable names,while `$to` and `$subject` are overwritten for the second email the concatenating variables..keep concatenating into a double mess.

Comment: I would comment out the mail functions and echo the variables to verify that your field are accurate.  Also, I would name the fields differently for the two mail operations.  $to might be $toFirstEmail and $toSecondEmail, respectively.

Comment: This worked. Changing the $ names to something different for the second email. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$to = "info@example.com;$_POST[email]"
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, because the recipients are suppose to receive two separate email messages - not the same message.