# Send two separate emails via one PHP page,

Tags: php, html

There are similar questions to this but they do not outline the specifics of my case, [Similar Question (Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348106/send-two-different-emails-after-form-submission)

```html
<form method="post" name="process.php" action="process.php">

Name:   <input type="text" name="name">

Email Address:  <input type="text" name="email">

Message:    <textarea name="message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Send Form">
</form>
```

This is saved as `index.php` within my `bookings` folder.

I have created this code to handle form submission, which does work.

```php
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
?>

<?php
    $email_from = $visitor_email;

    $email_subject = "New Form submission";

    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                            "Here is the message:\n $message".



  $to = "bookings@mycompany.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);


 ?>

<?php
 $to = "user@emailprovider.com";

  $headers = "From: 'bookings@mycompany.com' \r\n";

  $headers .= "Reply-To: 'bookings@mycompany.com' \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
  $email_body = "Hi, we have received your booking request, someone from the team will get back to you shortly"
?>

 <p>Sending Booking Request....</p>
```

I assume it has to do with the overlapping variables but I'd like to be able to send the user an email confirmation that their request has been received. At the moment the user does receive an email but it has the same contents as the email that is sent to `bookings@mycompany.com`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: just put you second `mail` function under the next line

Comment: Take a look at PHPMailer

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the email before you change the email body. Change to:

```
<?php
 $to = "user@emailprovider.com";

  $headers = "From: 'bookings@mycompany.com' \r\n";

  $headers .= "Reply-To: 'bookings@mycompany.com' \r\n";

  $email_body = "Hi, we have received your booking request, someone from the team will get back to you shortly";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: `$email_body` assigned after the mail send.

Replace

```
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
$email_body = "Hi, we have received your booking request, someone from the team will get back to you shortly"
```

with

```
$email_body = "Hi, we have received your booking request, someone from the team will get back to you shortly"
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```